# How to apply Sha2 for a particular column which is inside in the form of array struct in Hive or spark sql? Dynamically

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am having data in Hive

```
id    name       kyc
1001  smith      [pnno:999,ssn:12345,email:ss@mail.com]
```

when we select these columns the output will be

```
1001.smith, [999,12345,ss@mail.com]
```

I have to apply SHA2 inside this array column and also the output should display

```
1001,smith,[999,*****(sha2 masked value), ss@gmail.com]
```

The output should be same array struct format

I am currently creating a separate view and joining the query, Is there any way to handle this in a Hive query or inside spark/scala using dataframe Dynamically?

Also, using any config for spark/scala?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform` to encrypt the `ssn` field in the array of structs:

```
// sample dataframe
df.show(false)
+----+-----+---------------------------+
|id  |name |kyc                        |
+----+-----+---------------------------+
|1001|smith|[[999, 12345, ss@mail.com]]|
+----+-----+---------------------------+

// sample schema
df.printSchema
// root
// |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
// |-- name: string (nullable = false)
// |-- kyc: array (nullable = false)
// |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
// |    |    |-- pnno: integer (nullable = false)
// |    |    |-- ssn: integer (nullable = false)
// |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = false)

val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "kyc", 
    expr("""
        transform(kyc, 
            x -> struct(x.pnno pnno, sha2(string(x.ssn), 512) ssn, x.email email)
        )
    """)
)

df2.show(false)
+----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id  |name |kyc                                                                                                                                                   |
+----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1001|smith|[[999, 3627909a29c31381a071ec27f7c9ca97726182aed29a7ddd2e54353322cfb30abb9e3a6df2ac2c20fe23436311d678564d0c8d305930575f60e2d3d048184d79, ss@mail.com]]|
+----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks lot , Is there a way to deal on hive sql?

Comment: It's more troublesome to handle struct elements inside array of structs in Hive. I'd suggest using Spark for this.